# How to get MySQL multiple table backup with where condition in same backup file from java code?

Tags: java, mysql

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaJmp.png)I need to get selected table backup using java code with where condition for multiple tables. I have tryed somecode block and added below. Have to use same backup.sql file for two different table backup.

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv4X1.png)

```
try {
                String dbName = "gcc_db";
                String dbTable = "course";
                String dbTable_1 = "course_grade";
                String whereStatement = "\"" + 3 + "\"";
                String dbUser = "root";
                String dbPass = "admin";

                /***********************************************************/
                // Execute Shell Command
                /***********************************************************/
                String executeCmd1 = "";
                String executeCmd2 = "";                
                
                executeCmd1 = "C:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14/bin/mysqldump -u "+dbUser+" -p"+dbPass+" "+dbName+" "+dbTable+" --where=id="+whereStatement+" --single-transaction --skip-lock-tables --no-create-info -r D:/backup.sql";
                executeCmd2 = "C:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.14/bin/mysqldump -u "+dbUser+" -p"+dbPass+" "+dbName+" "+dbTable_1+" --where=course_id="+whereStatement+" --single-transaction --skip-lock-tables --no-create-info >> D:/backup.sql";
                System.out.println(executeCmd1);
                System.out.println(executeCmd2);
                Process runtimeProcess =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd1);
                int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
                if(processComplete == 0){

                System.out.println("Backup taken successfully");
                Process runtimeProcess1 =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd2);
                int processComplete1 = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
                if(processComplete1 == 0){
                    System.out.println("Backup taken successfully");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Could not take mysql backup:::::::::::2");
                }

                } else {

                    System.out.println("Could not take mysql backup:::::::::::1");

                }
                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();                   
                }
```

when i run the code only the first backup is running and got the output the second process is not writting the backup in file.

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.14, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: db
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.14

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `course`
--
-- WHERE:  id=3

LOCK TABLES `course` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `course` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `course` VALUES (3,'C0003','test-sample',2,'Test Sample');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `course` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2023-03-06 11:17:55
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: I think you need `int processComplete1 = runtimeProcess1.waitFor();` (wait for runtimeProcess1 instead of runtimeProcess)